# STL Sorting with Abstract Classes

Tags: c++, stl

I'm having a problem sorting my derived classes with the STL sort function.

Example -

The header:

```
vector<AbstractBaseClass *> *myVector;
```

In the ImpL:

```
sort(myVector->begin(), myVector->end(), compareBy);
```

The comparator:

```
bool MyClass::compareBy(AbstractBaseClass& a, AbstractBaseClass& b) {
    return (a->someMethod() < b->someMethod());
}
```

Edit: This question is geared toward general usage of sorting abstract classes with the STL (I'm not posting a trace dump). If its not apparent already, I'll say that there is no way in hell it can compile as printed. Rather, I'm asking (given the data structures) how one would typically sort with this toy abstract class.

Thanks for the quick answers, I believe you guys already nail'd it!

Got'a love StackOverFlow!

Comment: Real code, please. What does the vector hold, how is that defined? What is the problem? Compile errors, linker errors, not-expected-output?

Comment: And... *what* kind of problem do you have?

Comment: My advice - set a breakpoint inside your bool MyClass::compareBy() and check it.

Comment: that code won't compile..post some compilable code and state your problems clearly.

Comment: Pardon the ambiguity, but I felt some sample code was enough.
...and the answers I've received are already spot on. Thanks guys!

Comment: Shouldn't you mark an answer as accepted then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An example:

```
struct Abstr {
    virtual int some()const == 0;
    virtual ~Abstr() = default;
};

bool abstrSmaller( const Abstr* a1, const Abstr* a2 ) { 
   return a1->some() < a2->some(); 
}

int main() {
   vector<Abstr*> v;

   sort( v.begin(), v.end(), abstrSmaller );
}
```

1. The compare function should not be a member function: either a `static` or a free function.
2. It should take the `vector`'s elements as argument, i.e. a pointer, not a reference.
3. It can call `const` functions, so it can accept `const` arguments.

Answer (score 4):

1. That `compareBy` must not be a non-static member function (since this would require the implicit `this` pointer to be passed to the function by the compiler). You can either make it a static member, a free function, or a function object. The latter is generally better, as it usually allows better optimization (although in your code the abstraction penalty might undo that anyway).
2. The comparison must take your vector's `value_type`, and that's an `AbstractBaseClass*`, not an `AbstractBaseClass&`.

This would look like the following:

```
struct compareBy : public std::binary_function< const AbstractBaseClass*
                                              , const AbstractBaseClass*
                                              , bool > {
  bool operator()(const AbstractBaseClass* a, const AbstractBaseClass* b) {
    return (a->someMethod() < b->someMethod());
  }
};
```

You can also make this comparator a private member of your class, so it doesn't pollute any namespace.

Comment: For completeness, you'd want to inherit it from `binary_function`.